# I need to revert my last two "git pulls," I don't know anything else about the commit I need

Tags: git

In a nutshell I've done two git pulls and I need to revert back to before I did them. The first pull brought me forward at least 100 commits so I can't guess what commit ID I was on.

Is there any way for me to directly undo the pulls or otherwise find what commit ID I was on this morning?

Comment: Have you tried `git reflog`?

Comment: It seems close but it doesn't provide the info I need. The only commit ID I see in there is too new to be what I need. I see a "pull: Fast-Forward" that is probably the one I need to revert but it doesn't give any IDs

Comment: I was reading the logs wrong, I have what I need. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git reflog` will show you a history of actions. Each line starts with the SHA hash of the new commit you are on as a result of the action, i.e. the commit git moved to. Look for the line *before* the "pull" entry and that hash is the commit you were on before the pull.

In this example you'd move to "1234abc" with `git checkout 1234abc` or `git checkout HEAD@{2}`.

```
c831d9e HEAD@{0}: commit: add new feature
fe1c2f8 HEAD@{1}: pull: Fast-forward
1234abc HEAD@{2}: commit: add new data
39c842b HEAD@{3}: checkout: moving from master to feature
aa0b4b7 HEAD@{4}: checkout: moving from master to redis_xvdc
```

Answer (score 1):

```
git reflog
```

should print something like this :

```
859af32 HEAD@{0}: pull: Fast-forward <--- the pull you did
2bbb039 HEAD@{1}: <git command> <--- the point where you want to reset to
....
```

Then you can reset to the desired HEAD pointer :

```
git reset (--hard) HEAD@{1}
```

Comment: As always, be careful with `reset --hard`: it will overwrite your entire working directory, including dirty files that haven't yet been added to the index, without asking. It's a great tool, but don't use it unless you know what it does.